# How to add CSS class to the cloned div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I want to create something like "You're an idiot" hack that spawn some random stuff and the stuff is moving randomly. The issue is, the cloned div cannot be add with CSS modifier class.

What I currently doing is, I create a button that will spawn the same button infinitely. I want to make the cloned button to move randomly after they have been spawned. The problem is when I inspect, the spawned button cannot be added with CSS modifiers class. So the spawned buttons only spawned at random position but is not moving. Can tell me why I can't add CSS modifiers class on cloned div.

Here's my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n1wuwc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Where are you trying to add CSS modifier class? I don't get it, you can need `newButton.classList.add("foo")` or even just `newButton.className = "foo"`. But consider doing that Angular way to avoid obscure templating. You can store an array of all buttons currently visible and render them accordingly.

Comment: Oh I think I made a mistake. Not css modifier class, but what I thought is if I can put transform: translate(variableX, variableY) in ngStyle with some transitions it would work. But it won't. I think I need to rephrase my question. I'm sorry and thank you for your response sir.

Comment: _"Here's my stackblitz"_ - please go read [ask] and [mre]. Questions here need to be self-contained - the code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, and not just dumped onto an external testing platform.

Comment: Remember that in order for transition to work, elements need to have a state to transition *from*. When you add a new element, it won't transition. But it would animate, so when you need to run animation on mount, this is where `animation` property will work. However, in your case I'm assuming that buttons need to move all the time, so I'd suggest using transitions and periodically change their coordinations, so for example you place them randomly on the screen and then assign their new coordinations starting from minimal delay (0 time, but with `setTimeout` anyway).

Comment: Wow. That's some great explanation. Thank you for your answer @RoboRobok now I can imagine on how it should works. Really appreciated it.

Comment: @danial my pleasure, don't hesitate to open another question or edit this one if you hit the wall. If I can suggest something, try to do it Angular-way. You can store all coords in an array and add items there to generate new buttons, while also editing existing coords from time to time to make the existing buttons move to new places. If you synchronize animation length with these changes, you can achieve a really nicely looking effect :)

Comment: Sure man! Nice suggestions. Will definitely do that Angular-way so I can control the movements, animation delay and animation length in more efficient way‍♂️